# Exchange 365 can't send as alias

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365, alias

We're running Office 365 for a company. In Exchange admin, I have all domains added, I did enable "Send email as aliases" in Mail Flow settings, and I have added alias to my email address in Exchange Admin. But no matter what I do, I just can't send emails as that alias. Every piece of online documentation says to go into user settings > compose & reply > and to choose the alias here but there is no such setting on this page.